# How can I use the range operator with regexes when the text to match is not in $_?

Tags: perl, diamond-operator

I am trying to use the range operator while parsing a portion of a file. Basically, my code consists of:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>){
    if (/start/ .. /stop/){
        print; #print only lines between the two markers
    }
}
__DATA__
ignored 1
ignored 2
start
taken 1
taken 2
stop
ignored 3
```

My problem is that this code uses the implicit `$_` variable.

My actual code uses a variable to store the current line because I am making some changes to `$line` before testing it with the range operator. I have not found a way to use the `..` operator with an explicit variable. I have found a  workaround by assigning `$_` right before the test but that looks like an ugly hack to me:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (defined (my $line = <DATA>)){
    $_ = $line;
    if (/start/ .. /stop/){
        print $line;
    }
}
__DATA__
ignored 1
ignored 2
start
taken 1
taken 2
stop
ignored 3
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: `/start/` is shorthand for `$_ =~ /start/`. I think you can imagine the answer to your question given that!

Comment: @Borodin: yes, so I tried something like `if ($line =~ /start/ .. /stop/)` but obviously it failed. So it is a so trivial fix?

Comment: well, as much as `/start/` is shorthand for `$_ =~ /start/`, `/stop/` is shorthand for `$_ =~ /stop/`

Comment: So you have changed it to `$line =~ /start/ ... $_ =~ /stop/`. Anyway, you have the solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ($line =~ /start/ .. $line =~ /stop/) {
        print $line;
    }
}
```

Comment: So simple that I did not find it... Thanks!